# Invite Existing Contacts to Create Linked Drupal User Account

Tags: user-account, drupal-9

I have quite a few existing contacts who do not have Drupal accounts. I want to send out an email to these contacts with an invititation for them to create their own Drupal user account. All their relevant details are stored in Civi (email, first name and last name). I don't want to bulk create them as it will be each individual contact's choice if they want to create an account. If possible, I don't want them to re-enter any of their details. Is there a way I can send out a bulk email which would have a unique link to automatically create an account for that recipient? Or could I send them a link to a form where they just have to enter their (unique) email (and possibly username/password) and submit, and this would create the account? Or maybe a pre-filled form?

It is important that when they create their account, they receive a new account notification email with a login link. It does not matter if they do not choose their username and password, if these can be generated automatically, or it is fine if they enter these when creating their account.

I'm using Civi 5.46 with Drupal 9.3.

Answer (score 2):

you will need to either use Drupal registration form(/user/register) or [profile with user registration turned on](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/#drupal-user-account-registration-option).

The new account notification should be received if your Drupal user settings have it turned on.

Comment: and send an email link to that profile with a checksum so they do not need to enter any of their details again

Comment: Thanks very much for the input. Will try the methods you suggested. The email link to a profile with a checksum sounds very promising. Thanks again.